# Static resource not avaliable in folder like servlet path

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a web project structure:

```
src/main/webapp
           |__project1
                 |____css
           |__WEB-INF
                 |____project1
                         |_____jsp
```

Part of my web.xml:

```
<servlet-name>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-lass>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   ...
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/project1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In my jsp page I use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=${pageContext.request.contextPath}/project1/css/common.css type="text/css"/>
```

But it's not work. Stylesheet is not available on page.
If I use localhost:9080/project1/css/common.ccs I recieve 404 error.
If I transfer ccs file in folder: src/main/webapp/css, then css is avaliable (localhost:9080/css/common.css).
I think problem in /project1/* intercept servlet and I can't access from css.
How fix this problem and save the old architecture?

Comment: add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` to the configuration of the dispatcher servlet. Or don't map the servlet to `/project1`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/project1` while trying to access the resources. Since you have already mapped it inside `web.xml`, it will be available in the `contextPath`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/common.css type="text/css"/>
```